# Why can't I clean my tycho project with maven clean?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I'm facing below issue, is there any hint to help me out?
Thanks.

I have a project set up as below:

```
C:\workspace
 |-------com.myorg.myplugin.tycho
 |-------com.myorg.myplugin1
 |-------com.myorg.myplugin2
 |-------com.myorg.myplugin.feature
 |-------com.myorg.mylpugin.repository
```

`com.myorg.myplugin2` is a plug-in project, and it is a dependency of the `com.myorg.myplugin1` plug-in project. Both of the project are included as `module` in the `tycho` parent project.

I'm able to run `maven clean package` successfully in `tycho` project. But when I try to run only `maven clean`, following error occurs:

> org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project mygroup:com.myorg.myplugin1:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact mygroup:com.myorg.myplugin2:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

--> why is it looking for a `jar` artifact???

The `pom.xml` files of two plug-in projects are very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.myorg.myplugin.tycho</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../com.myorg.myplugin.tycho/</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.myorg.myplugin1</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.myorg.myplugin.tycho</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../com.myorg.myplugin.tycho/</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.myorg.myplugin2</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Without all pom files you are using we are not able to help...

Comment: @khmarbaise: thanks for the comment, I finally solve it with helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally able to solve this with the help of some colleagues. This happened because I've never run `install` goal before. Once I did it, `clean` works as normal. I'm not sure why, but it works :)

Comment: Then let me educate you why it works: `mvn install` places your build’s output (a JAR, most likely) into your local Maven repository (`~/.m2/repository`), where another invocation of `mvn` can find it. This is necessary if the project you are building depends on another project not in the current “reactor” (the set of all projects you are building *right now*); if its dependencies are not in the local (or a remote) Maven repository, then the project cannot be build. (FYI, you can prevent Tycho from looking in the local repository using `-Dtycho.localArtifacts=ignore`.)

Comment: You should check you build by deleting the local repository first and than simply do `mvn clean package` this should work also without any issue..if not than you have a wrong build...